macOS Menu Bar Appearing on Wrong Monitor when `auto-hide` is set to `always`
There is a way to hide the menu bar on Mac (macOS Sonoma and others).
When hovering the mouse pointer over the top of the screen, the menu bar shows, and when moving the mouse pointer away from the top, the menu bar retracts away from view again .
The issue is, when having multiple displays and focusing on an app in Display 1, then hovering the mouse pointer over the top of the screen in Display 2, the menu bar shows in Display 1, not in Display 2 where the mouse pointer is.
To me, this is a bug in Mac os, but it's worth asking; is there a workaround for this which doesn't involve showing the menu bar always?

